# nested constraint in simple java score calculation is very slow

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to build 3 nested constraints with OptaPlanner. It works, but it's very slow (even for a very small data set)... Maybe someone does have an idea how to improve the performance?

```
// pseudocode
first_constraint = false;
second_constraint = false;
third_constraint = false;

if (first_constraint == true) {
   if (second_constraint == true) {
      if (third_constraint == false) {score--;}
   } else {score--;}
} else {score--;}
```

Comment: What ScoreCalculator type are you using? What's your average score calculation count per second (as shown in the info log statement after solving)? (should be > 1000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Score calculation performance tricks](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#scoreCalculationPerformanceTricks). Especially the section about incremental score calculation.

Comment: thanks for your answer... The score calculation performance tricks helped! I improved the average score calculation count per second. Now it's about 4000. I will try to improve it further :)